# Find the coefficients and convergence of radius of $\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$.

Tags: calculus, power-series

I am trying to find the coefficients and convergence of radius of $\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$.

---

From the Taylor series, I know around $x=x_0$
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} (x-x_0)^n
\end{align}
and I know for the power series
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n  \quad \textrm{converges} \quad |x|<R, 
\end{align}
where $R$ is the radius of convergence given by $\alpha = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|$. i.e.,
\begin{align}
R = \begin{cases}
&\frac{1}{\alpha}, \quad 0<\alpha <\infty \\
& \infty, \quad \alpha = 0 \\
& 0 ,\quad \alpha = \infty
\end{cases}
\end{align}

---

First my starting point is find the explicit form of $a_n$ of $\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}$. Simply denote $g(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}$ then

After some computations I have
\begin{align}
g'(x) = \frac{e^{-x} x}{(1-x)^2}, \quad g''(x) =   \frac{e^{-x}(1+x^2)}{(1-x)^3}, 
\quad g'''(x) = \frac{e^{-x} (2+3x+x^2)}{(1-x)^4}, 
\end{align}
I can put $x=x_0$ but couldn't figure out the general form of $a_n$.

Is there any smart method to compute $a_n$?

For the radius of convergence, I guess only after figuring out explicit or asymptotic behaviour of $a_n$ it can be determined. ...

Comment: Radius of convergence should be $1$ because the function has a pole at $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication of a power series $(a_0,a_1,\dots)$ by $\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots$ produces the series $(a_0,a_0+a_1,a_0+a_1+a_2,\dots)$ Since
$$e^{-x}=\frac1{0!}x^0-\frac1{1!}x^1+\frac1{2!}x^2-\frac1{3!}x^3+\cdots$$
it follows that
$$\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}=\frac1{0!}x^0+\left(\frac1{0!}-\frac1{1!}\right)x^1+\left(\frac1{0!}-\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}\right)x^2+\cdots$$
The radius of convergence around $0$ is $1$, the same as that of $\frac1{1-x}$.